# How to compare list of files with different extensions and delete extra files?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have 2 folders one contains images files and the second contains text files each text file have the same name as the image file and contains information about the image.eg:

```
   -Labels:
     -1.txt
     -2.txt
     -3.txt
     -6.txt
   -Images:
     -1.jpg
     -2.jpg
     -3.jpg
     -4.jpg
     -5.jpg
     -6.jpg
```

I want to delete images who has not a text file(in this example:4.jpg,5.jpg), I found a method how to determinate the different files but I can't delete them.

```
diff <(ls -1 ./Images | sed s/.jpg//g) <( ls -1 ./Labels | sed s/.txt//g)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a small bash script that can help you to solve this task:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for file in Images/*.jpg
do
    if [[ ! -f "Labels/$(basename ${file%.*}).txt" ]]
    then
        echo rm "$file"
    fi
done
```

- Remove `echo` to do the actual changes.

The script must be executed in the parent directory, here it is formatted as inline command:

```bsh
for f in Images/*.jpg; do if [[ ! -f "Labels/$(basename ${f%.*}).txt" ]]; then echo rm "$f"; fi; done
```

Comment: I am way too fond of sed, your solution is more elegant, thanks!

Comment: In `zsh` you can use `${file:r}` instead of `${file%.*}` to get the filename minus one extension. It's smarter about what that means, which can be an advantage over substring matches when you're dealing with mixed paths that don't all fit a simple pattern. (e.g. `file="foo.bar/baz"; echo ${file:r}` will return `foo.bar/baz`, not `foo`. Though `file="foo.bar/.baz"` will produce `foo.bar/` by either method, so some care is still required.)

Answer (score 6):

I think I would do it like this:

```bsh
for i in Images/*; do file=`echo $i | sed -e 's/jpg/txt/' -e 's/Images/Labels/'`; if [ ! -f "$file" ] ; then rm $i ; fi; done
```

If you want to make sure it works , before actually using it try this first:

```bsh
for i in Images/*; do file=`echo $i | sed -e 's/jpg/txt/' -e 's/Images/Labels/'`; if [ ! -f "$file" ] ; then echo rm $i ; fi; done
```

It will show which commands will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
cd /path/to/Images
LIST=$(find /path/to/Labels -iname *.txt -printf "%f|" | sed 's/.txt/.jpg/g')
rm -i !($LIST)
```

1. Generates a list of `txt` files.
2. Changes their extension to `jpg`.
3. Removes anything that is not on the list.

   - `-i` is just for safety.